# Should I install tns-platform-declarations package as a "dependency" or a "dev-dependency"?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

One of the popular package used during developing NativeScript apps is [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations)

But should I install it as dependency or a dev-dependency?

Answer (score 2):

It's a **dev-dependency**

It's just a set of TypeScript declaration files for intellisense support.

Comment: +1 I want to add that those files are really really BIG. Adding them as a `dependency` is not simply a bad practice but will also cause the build app to be significantly larger than expected. Always add them as a `devDependency`

Answer (score 1):

On second thought (and after some additional research) with **NativeScript 6**, the webpack bundle is enabled by default. That means that all code is tree-shaken and only JavaScript files that are imported will be included in your outputted bundle (which will guarantee a smaller bundle size compared to the legacy workflow). As `tns-platform-declaration` is never imported those *.d.ts files will be tree shaken and not included in the bundle.

So with NativeScript 6 and above, there is no difference if the `tns-platform-declarations` will be a `dependency` or a `devDependency` BUT it is a good practice to differentiate the development libraries. So I would say that you should install it as a `devDependency` just to be more clear.